# How to call a controller function from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the simplest way to call a controller's functions from another controller?

I have controller like this..

**Controller1**

```
$scope.setTitleKey = function (titleKey) {
        $scope.currentTitleKey = titleKey;
        $scope.getDetails();
    };
```

**Controller2**

```
$scope.getDetails=  function () {
        if (titleKey !== "All") {
            $scope.bookInfo;
            bookDetails.getBookDetails(titleKey).then(function (results) {
                $scope.bookInfo = results.data;
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error.data.message);
            }
            );
        };
    };
```

I just want to call function from other controller

The simple logic is that if the function from **Controller1** then the another function is call from the **Controller2**

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a **factory** or **service** when you want to share code in your controller

it is the best way to get all the function and variable which you want to share like

```
Modulename.factory("ABC",function(){// Modulename which you have make on your code it is just for a example
var test=0;
return {
    /** by this get test var**/
    "getABC":function(){

        return test;
    },

   /**to set new new test value 
    * **/
    "setABC":function(passtest){
        test=passtest;

    }
};

});
```

Now use in **Controller 1**

```
$scope.setTitleKey = function (titleKey,ABC) {
  ABC.getABC();//get 0;
  ABC.setABC(5);

 };
```

Now use in **Controller 2**

```
$scope.getDetails=  function () {
       ABC.getABC();// get 5
    };
```

Here i am sharing a logic which you can implement and for more search in angular doc it will helpful

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot.. and thanks for the example guide for me.. i got it

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that don't even try to communicate between controllers, instead use one of the communications patterns

1. Using a shared service (**PREFERRED**).
2. Using events `$emit()`, `$on()` and `$broadcast()`
3. Use scope inheritance.

As mentioned in the comments, these options in the in the order of best practices.

Comment: +1 for shared service... +0.5 for events -1 for scope inheritance.